# Textview in a fragment of Viewpager doesn't update right

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs

I have created A layout and I dynamically add tabs according to data I receive. I do the same with fragments updating the Text View dynamically. Although when the layout loads and if I swipe through the fragments or view pager (sorry I am new to all these hope my terminology is right) they update just okay (meaning there is sometimes lag in updating not much of an issue) and with right data. although, if in fresh I open the layout and click on tab to change my fragments I get no data or wrong data. **Example:-** when Layout loads for first time my first & third tab load up fine. If I click on a second Tab (not swiping but touching the tabs on top for the whole time), my second tab doesn't have any data in its fragment. On moving round here and there selecting tabs randomly first tab loads second tabs data, but second tab never loads anything. Its not the same when I swipe if I load page new or for first time.
Let me know where I am doing wrong. Thank you.

**Here is my code:-**

Layout file - **show_score.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.lp.activity.ShowScorePassagesActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/children_school"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBackBar"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include android:id="@+id/appBackBar"
            layout="@layout/detail_appbar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/passagetabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment File - **fragment_show_score_passage.xml**

```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lp.activity.ShowScorePassagesActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/showScore"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:linksClickable="true"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
            </ScrollView>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardView4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style">
                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/fluencyAudioGrid"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
                    android:columnWidth="120dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
                    layout="@layout/icons_for_dashboard"
                    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scroolbar_style"
          android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scroolbar_style_background">
                </GridView>
            </ScrollView>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the main Java File where the magic happens - ShowScorePassageActivity.java

```
    public class ShowScorePassagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    public GridView gridView;
    public ArrayList<String> gridItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static TextView fragTextView;
    static String fragNewTextView = "";
    public static ArrayList<String> fluencyMarksList = new ArrayList<>();
    public TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_score_passages);

        Intent in = getIntent();
        String intentData = in.getStringExtra("intentData");
        String fluencyMarks = in.getStringExtra("fluencyMarks");
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.passagetabs);
        String mFluencyMarkList []= fluencyMarks.split("@");
        fluencyMarksList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(mFluencyMarkList));
        int count = 1;
        int counts=fluencyMarksList.size();
        for(int i = 0; i < counts; i++){
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Passage "+count));
            count=count+1;
        }
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                int position =  tab.getPosition();
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    if (position ==0){
                        fragTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(fluencyMarksList.get(0), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
                    }
                    else if (position ==1){
                        fragTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(fluencyMarksList.get(1) , Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
                    }
                    else if (position ==2){
                        fragTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(fluencyMarksList.get(2) , Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (position ==0){
                        fragTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(fluencyMarksList.get(0)));
                    }
                    else if (position ==1){
                        fragTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(fluencyMarksList.get(1)));
                    }
                    else if (position ==2){
                        fragTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(fluencyMarksList.get(2)));
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                fragTextView.setText("");
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_show_score_passages, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_score_passages, container, false);
            fragTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showScore);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

                fragTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(fluencyMarksList.get(0) , Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
            } else {

                fragTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(fluencyMarksList.get(0)));
            }
            return rootView;
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        int mNumOfTabs;
        Fragment fragment = null;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
            super(fm);
            this.mNumOfTabs=NumOfTabs;

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mNumOfTabs;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit (3);`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

**It is only a example of what worked for me in the hopes of helping you**

In `OnCreate`:

```
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
this.addPages(mViewPager);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.mTab_ID);
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(listener(mViewPager));
```

Then add the fragments to the `TabLayout` by doing:

```
//ADD ALL PAGES TO TABLAYOUT
private void addPages(ViewPager pager) {
    adapter = new MyFragPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addPage(new FragmentAdapter1());
    adapter.addPage(new FragmentAdapter2());
    adapter.addPage(new FragmentAdapter3());

    //SET ADAPTER TO PAGER
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Then implement `TabLayout` click events `OnTabSelectedListener` by doing:

```
//TabLayout Click Events
private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener listener(final ViewPager pager) {
    return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: (sorry newbie here) will this help in dynamic data. My requirement is to add tabs dynamically according to data I will receive.. like if there is 2 count then 2 tabs are shown. Same goes with fragment data if there are two tabs each tab gets its own respective data dynamically and is set into text view.

Comment: With the example I have given, there is 3 Fragments that are being populated in the `ViewPager` (you can change it to how many you like), the data of the fragments (that you receive) should be handled within the fragment itself.